# How do I view the medal punchcards in Fortnite Battle Royale Chapter 2 Season 1?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

How do I view the medal punchcards? I want to know what I have to do in order to get them, but I don't know how to open them up.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Go to the lobby and where your xp bar and challenges would be, your medal punchcard will be there too.